# Unable to get Dynamic SQL to pass a dynamic table parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Not worried about SQL Injection or anything of the like, just trying to get this to work. Using SSMS and Visual Studio.

I have C# code that passes a variable, GlobalVariables.username, to an SQL parameter.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkIntrotoPublicSpeaking.Checked || checkEffectiveOralCommunication.Checked || checkProfComm.Checked)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> sqlOralComm = new List<SqlParameter>();
        sqlOralComm.Add(new SqlParameter("Username", GlobalVariables.username));
        sqlOralComm.Add(new SqlParameter("IntrotoPublicSpeaking", cboxIntrotoPublicSpeaking.Text));
        sqlOralComm.Add(new SqlParameter("EffectiveOralCommunication", cboxEffectiveOralCommunication.Text));
        sqlOralComm.Add(new SqlParameter("ProfComm", cboxProfComm.Text));
        DAL.ExecSP("CreateOralComm", sqlOralComm);
    }
}
```

I've been reading into Dynamic SQL and saw that to pass the table name as a parameter, you have to construct it manually and execute it as "SET..." etc, etc. I've been trying slightly different modifications of the last 3 lines below. Each time, I'm greeted with an "invalid syntax near ..." exception pertaining to different parts of that line. In stack exchange it's broken into 3 lines but in SSMS it's one line, a little easier to read.

Status is nvarchar column and Course is an int column.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateOralComm]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Username nvarchar(30),
    @IntrotoPublicSpeaking nvarchar(3),
    @EffectiveOralCommunication nvarchar(3),
    @ProfComm nvarchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max)
    SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @Username + ' SET Grade = ' + 
    @IntrotoPublicSpeaking + ' Status = "Completed" WHERE Course = 7600105';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

I know that global variable works, I have another line of code that's just a MessageBox displaying the value and it's correct. Just can't get those last few lines of SQL to work. I'm trying out just this first part, @IntrotoPublicSpeaking, before I move onto the other 2.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The fact that you even need to resort to such dynamic SQL means that your data model is broken as it's using data (the content of the `@userName` variale) as meta data (the table name). Unless you have different tables describing unrelated business entities that just happen to share the same columns, the correct solution would be to unite all these tables into a single table, adding a column to distinguish between different users.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

```
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @Username + ' SET Grade = ' + 
@IntrotoPublicSpeaking + ' Status = "Completed" WHERE Course = 7600105';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Missing comma before Status and I think you do need to use single quotes

```
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @Username + ' SET Grade = ' + 
@IntrotoPublicSpeaking + ', Status = ''Completed'' WHERE Course = 7600105';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: That's probably going to fix the reported problem (the syntax error) but it's not a solution, it's a workaround. The proper solution is to refactor the database. See my comment to the question for details.

Comment: @ZoharPeled agreed, but I bet he's getting the invalid syntax due to these errors.

Comment: I agree - that's why I started my comment with "That's probably going to fix the reported problem"...

Comment: @hardkoded System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Status'.' is what it's telling me now. I'll keep messing with it, thank you though!

Comment: `Status` is a keyword in SQL Server, you might need to use square brackets around it: `[Status]`.